# excess blank line is printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

> so I want to read a text file and print its all content in uppercase
> character. I written the code and it's correct also. But I don't know
> why the excess blank line is printing between the two line.

```
import pickle
file=open("STORY.TXT",'r')
string=file.readlines()
for x in string:
    print(x.upper())
file.close()
```

> output

```
@AN ORANAGE IS WRONG

@WRONG

@APPLE 

@IS GOOD

@FOR YT IN SE

@AA

@AA
```

> desired output

```
@AN ORANAGE IS WRONG
@WRONG
@APPLE 
@IS GOOD
@FOR YT IN SE
@AA
@AA
```

Comment: I think it because of escape sequence , but I am not sure. Please any one can explain the execution.

Comment: `file.readlines` keeps the line separators on each line.  Try `print(x.strip().upper())`.

Comment: You don't need to read the entire file into memory first; you can iterate over `file` directly. Also, use `with open(...) as file: ...`: you won't have to call `file.close()` explicitly, and your file will be closed even if an uncaught exception is raised in the body of the `with` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `.readlines` without arguments you get trailing newlines, `print` add newlines by default, hence blank lines. You should instruct `print` to not add anything, that is do

```
file=open("STORY.TXT",'r')
string=file.readlines()
for x in string:
    print(x.upper(),end="")
file.close()
```

Comment: can you explain more about it

Comment: The only argument you *can* pass to `readlines` has nothing to do with the trailing newlines.

Comment: `file.readlines()` returns something like `['foo\n', 'bar\n']`, not `['foo', 'bar']`.